# How to run multiple lines of cin?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I think that you're supposed to use cin.getline?

I'm trying to ask the month and amount of rainfall, then after they've inputted that I want the second month and amount of rainfall, and then again for the third month. After that I simply take the average of those.

But when I run my code you can only input the first month and amount of rainfall, then it just couts the following two questions without allowing you to answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
double r1, r2, r3, rA;
int m1, m2, m3;


std::cout << "Average Rainfall Calculator\n";

std::cout << "Please enter your first month followed by the amount of rain in inches:\n";
std::cin >> m1;
std::cin >> r1;

std::cout << "\nPlease enter your second month followed by the amount of rain in inches:\n";
std::cin >> m2;
std::cin >> r2;

std::cout << "\nPlease enter your third month followed by the amount of rain in inches:\n";
std::cin >> m3;
std::cin >> r3;

rA = (r1 + r2 + r3) / 3;

std::cout << "The amount of rainfall for: " << m1 << ", " << m2 << ", and " << m3 << "is " << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << rA << "inches of rain.\n";

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: "*I missed the class today ... so I wasn't able to see how they went about that*" - so why not just ask your teacher to explain what you missed? "*when I run my code ... it just couts the following two questions without allowing you to answer*" - what are your variables declared as? What does your input look like? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. My guess is your input is failing, setting the `failbit` or `badbit` state on `cin`, which you are not testing for or clearing

Comment: Hi Remy, I've edited the code to show the full code I've got going on! My teacher is from Korea and doesn't explain well at all in English but it's his examples that were much needed. I don't have anybody's number from the class either since it's only the second week, didn't think I'd need it so soon since I've been healthy. Thank you for the help Remy!

Comment: `m1`, `m2` and `m3` are numbers but you probably input text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m1`, `m2` and `m3` are numbers but you probably input text. Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main()
{
double r1, r2, r3, rA;
std::string m1, m2, m3;


std::cout << "Average Rainfall Calculator\n";

std::cout << "Please enter your first month followed by the amount of rain in inches:\n";
std::cin >> m1;
std::cin >> r1;

std::cout << "\nPlease enter your second month followed by the amount of rain in inches:\n";
std::cin >> m2;
std::cin >> r2;

std::cout << "\nPlease enter your third month followed by the amount of rain in inches:\n";
std::cin >> m3;
std::cin >> r3;

rA = (r1 + r2 + r3) / 3;

std::cout << "The amount of rainfall for: " << m1 << ", " << m2 << ", and " << m3 << "is " << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << rA << "inches of rain.\n";

}
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Such an easy fix too. I tried to ask my professor about when to use strings and when to use int but he didn't understand my question. This explains it so easily. Thanks so much Thomas. Have a great day.